# vertical and horizontal scrolling like Pulse application

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, horizontallist

My application requires both horizontal scroll and vertical scroll together. The number of view items in both the direction are dynamic and will be fetched from database 10 at a time (horizontal direction). How can I implement this ?

I tried using listview + horizontal listview (http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). But the problem coming is..when I click a button to append next 10 items in a row in horizontal direction. Next stories appended are not being displayed. When i scroll vertically and that particular row is not visible then again when i scroll it back..the next appended stories are visible.

Any solution to my implementation ? or any other suggestion/idea to implement vertical+horizontal scroll which will fulfill my purpose ??